# sql commands not working using php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display last visit of a user in my page.
The commands seems ok, but it doesn't work.
I have tried everything. 
DATABASE SELECTION-OK 
TABLE SELECTION-OK 
if($result)- EXECUTES 
but the UPDATE and the details I can not fetch from database.
Here's the code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","counter");
$qry = "SELECT * FROM nodupes WHERE ids_hash = 'ids_hash'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
if($result)
{   
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $lastvisit = $data["lastvisit"];
    $timex = time() - $lastvisit;
}
$curr_time = time();
$qry2 = "update nodupes set lastvisit='$curr_time' WHERE ids_hash='ids_hash'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$qry2);
```

What should I do? The lastvisit in the database always shows 0
[image: databse tble]

Comment: Doesn't look like the `ids_hash` column contains a literal `'ids_hash'`.

Comment: you can modify your update like this, `UPDATE nodupes SET lastvisit=current_timestamp WHERE ids_hash='ids_hash'`

Comment: @OleksandrPobuta tried both current_timestamp & current_timestamp() - didn't work. the lastvisit still shows 0 ;(

Comment: So you have maybe a variable called `$ids_hash`?

Comment: @OleksandrPobuta It would not work, it has the same problem as OP code.

Comment: @mario it does contains. i have included the phpcount.php above these queries, which contains the correct value of ids_hash

Comment: @dWinder yes. i have included the phpcount.php above these queries, which contains the correct value of ids_hash

Comment: @WillsonMarandi, Judging by your screen from db - it does not. You are trying to select a record that has a column `ids_hash` with a value `'ids_hash'`. But, agan, judging by the screens there is no such column.

Comment: @OleksandrPobuta OP code? well, isn't there another way ?

Comment: u can try hardcode the ids_hash value into the quotes and see if that works

Comment: So can you add to your question the `ids_hash` variable and his content. What @mario and I claiming the you have the value you want to look for in that variable but in your SQL query you use the string "ids_hash" instead of your variable

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Hey, thanks, I just forgot to sha256 it. thanks friend. my bad.

Comment: you all are very kind and helpful. thanks again